# linux minimal block size

Tags: filesystems, storage, block

### Question  :

I would like to know if one could create an empty partition with a very small block size, say 100 bytes, and get their experience on the long run.

Are there any gotchas ?

### Context :

I know many filesystems set the default block size to 4Kb.
Some more, some less (512B)

It is not for a filesystem but rather a storage disk that is small (40 Gb)

My average doc size is 80-100 bytes.

### The why :

Getting experienced user experience

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocksizes has to be a multiple of the sector size, and all types of media I have ever worked with has had a sector size of 512 bytes or more.

If you want efficient storage of files much smaller than 512 bytes, you need to use a filesystem designed for that purpose. I know reiserfs is designed to perform tail-packing of files smaller than 12KB, which would permit storing multiple small files inside one sector.

I guess there also exists more modern filesystem with similar features, but I don't know any specific filesystem with this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Anything below 512 bytes would be fundamentally useless as the sector size (and therefore smallest allocation unit) of a disk is 512 bytes (4K with newer, large disks) and there is no way around that.

BTW: What does

> Getting experienced user experience

even mean?

Comment: it is a syntactic recursion :)